# Rails many_to_many table not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

I'm not able to get a many_to_many table to update when I create a new site record.  The sites table is updated, but not the sites_users. I'm expecting the user_id and the site_id to be added to the sites_users table when the site is created.

My migration:

```
class CreateTableSiteUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
  create_table :sites_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :site_id
      t.integer :user_id
  end
```

Models:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible  :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_id
has_secure_password
has_and_belongs_to_many :sites
```

site.rb

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :site_key, :organization_id, :user_id, :site_id
belongs_to :organization
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

sites_controller.rb

```
def create
  @site = Site.new(params[:site])
    @site.organization_id = Organization.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    @user_id = current_user.id
    if @site.save
        flash[:success] = "New Site Created!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
```

What else do I need to get the site_id and the user_id to save to the sites_users join table?

I have read as much as possible on the many to many and has many through topics posted, watched the railscast video, and searched as much as I can.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a new site on the `create` action, and want to assign that site to the `current_user`, try the following

```
if @site.save
  @site.users << current_user
  flash[:success] = "New Site Created!"
  redirect_to root_path
else
  ...
```

This adds `current_user` to the list of users of `@site` but only after `@site` passes validations and gets saved.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much, I was trying to figure this out for weeks!